# How many options there are to test an iOS app in a device?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipa

I need send to other people my iOS app in objective-c before upload this to apple store. I have an apple developer account and I know the UDID of all devices to test the app.

Could I use .ipa to test in other devices? I know testFlight, but are there other ways to test?
Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html IT is very easy to Google and find the documentations. This question is not fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Other than TestFlight, which is really easy to use, you can install an IPA file using iTunes when your device is connected. You need an Ad-Hoc build including the UDID of the device you want to install the application to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TestFlight you can send your development build using diawi.com
it's an platform to create your build link and install it on device that you have added UDID before.

Steps

1) Create your development IPA file.
2) Go to Diawi.com
3) Drag & Drop your IPA.(Until Processing completed 100%)
4) Click on Send.
5) Copy link and install.

I think it will help you.

Other one is Testgrid.io, same as diawi.com

Hope you understand it better.